# How to make one page website without # in url like exp.com/sec1 instead of exp.com/#sec1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a websited which is working fine, but I want to add clean url like exp.com/sec1 instead of exp.com/#sec1, I have kind of achive it with History.pushState but when someone reloads the link it takes them to different page not the same page as its redirecting to sec1. how to achive this I have seen websites doing this like https://nicholasmunt.com/, and I also want the page to take me to the section which is mentioned in url when page loads.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to use # still. I have implemented sate using History.pushState here http://hedge.cloud-2.co.uk/#how-we-do-it and the senior dev recommended using # even though I wanted it to look cleaner like yourself.